# Why is a specific question down voted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, voting, down-votes

The question in question here is the following: [My colleague keeps microwaving fish at work, how can I stop this](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/23969/1599)

It would really be nice to understand why the question gets down voted. I thought the reason for votes ito questions has to to with its relevance. I honestly fail to see how this question isn't of the utmost relevance. This sort of thing probably goes on in thousands of places every day.

Comment: In addition to Tink's great answer, I'd just like to point out that "relevance" isn't a great metric for question quality. The scope of our site can't by any means cover every possible question involving a human (which some questions seem to assume), regardless of relevance. For an easy example of something extremely relevant that would still be closed here, see [our policy on "pickup" questions](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2347/11811).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I beg your pardon and you people have probably just caught me out, but I'm really trying to get the penny to drop here. I'm now analysing the 'Pickup' issue (link in your comment) to work out what exactly all of this stuff means. I really appreciate your trouble. The problem probably began at the junction where I took it for granted that roughly any 'relevant' question would be acceptable - irrespective of whether it could have a solution in terms of what I only now begin to grasp the aim of the interpersonal skills site is. Steep learning curve, this one.

Answer (score 7):

If you hover over the downvote button, it says:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Given that 'official' reason for downvotes, and numerous feature requests on Meta SE asking about forcing people to give a reason for downvoting, all being declined, a question asking why things are downvoted isn't a good approach.

Instead of asking why it has downvotes, we should probably ask ourselves why it doesn't have any close votes, comments asking for more clarification or comments explaining why this question is unuseful on a site about Interpersonal Skills (behaviors used to interact with people well).

Even this question here doesn't make a strong case for the current question showing research effort, being a clear and useful addition to a site about behaviors used to interact with people well, besides that apparently 'there *may* be more places where people microwave fish, sabotage the microwave and vote against microwaving fish'.

Comment: Just added a comment along those lines, thanks for the reminder ;) (IMO it's "unclear", but I'm also hesitant to single-handedly close vote, especially when it's clearly been looked at by a number of people already who all chose *not* to close vote for whatever reason...)